# How would I make my javascript timeout for only 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, function, timeout, seconds

If 4e3 is equal to 4 seconds. What would I use for 3 Secs? or 2 Secs?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
$( function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
        $('#loadingque').trigger('click');
    }, 4e3);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 17):

If you *understand* why `4e3` is 4000 then you can figure out what 3000 looks like. `eN` means `10 to the power N`, so 3 times 10 to the power 3 is 3000, or `3e3`.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to have negative powers of `N`, so `1e-1 === 0.1`. I think there's a sort-of-convention for always including the sign, so really you should use `3e+3` not `3e3`.

Comment: Never heard of such convention (at least in JS). Don't see how that can be useful tho, I mean `+` in front of a positive number means nothing, and `3e-3` is easy enough to spot.

Comment: @broox I encountered this notation in minified javascript files. I think it makes sense there. It's shorter to write 4e3 than 4000.

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {`enter code here`
    //hide a div after 3 seconds
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#div').hide();",3000 );
});
```

Hope these will help u..

Answer (score 2):

It takes milliseconds

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.write(new Date());
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var runCount = 0;
var maxCount = 1000000;

function timerMethod()
{
    runCount++;
    if(runCount >= maxCount)
    {
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }
    $('#loadingque').trigger('click');
    console.log(runCount + "of" + maxCount);
}

var timerId = setInterval(timerMethod, 3000);
```

this is running every 3000ms for maxCount times